# Azure AD Authentication for Xamarin Application Fails Authentication on Downstream Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I've built an ASP.NET core Web App calling an ASP.NET Core Web API that is secured using Azure AD as described [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg).

I've also built a Xamarin mobile application that authenticates to the Web App's Azure App Service and utilizes the downstream Web API as described [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2).

The Web App can access the API without issue; however, the Xamarin application fails with an HTTP Response Message: Unauthorized.

Utilizing the guidance from the Microsoft Identity team [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Web-API-Troubleshooting), I was able to track down the cause of the failure.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

A snippet from the source code for the requirement shows where it fails. Specifically, it is on the IsAuthenticated check.

```
public class DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = context.User;
        var userIsAnonymous =
            user?.Identity == null ||
            !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);
        if (!userIsAnonymous)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Tracing the code from the working Web App, the context is generated as shown below. The critical point is the GetAccessTokenForUserAsync method gets an access token for a downstream API on behalf of the user account for which the claims are provided in the User member of the controller's HttpContext parameter.

```
...
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

await PrepareAuthenticatedClient();

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://example.com/api/mycontroller");
...

private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
{
    var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "api://xxxx/.default"});
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

[image]

Tracing the code from the failing Xamarin application, the context is generated as shown below.

```
...
PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
   .Create(ClientID)
   .WithTenantId(TenantID)
   .WithRedirectUri($"msal{ClientID}://auth")
   .Build();

authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive("api://xxxx/.default").ExecuteAsync();

var result = Network.GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(authToken);
...

public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(string token)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://example.com/api/mycontroller");
    message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

[image]

How do get the authenticated user into the HTTP context for the Xamarin application?

Comment: Try with this tutorial [User Authentication in Xamarin with Azure AD B2C](https://dev.to/425show/user-authentication-in-xamarin-with-azure-ad-b2c-4clm)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try it on a client like postman. Also, Is the bearer token base64 encoded?